# Set Background Color in jqGrid Footer Row

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

The following code will not change the background color.

```
function gComplete(){

        var $grid = $('#timesheetlineitemsqueue');
        var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'totals', false, 'sum');
        $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'totals': colSum });
        $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'day7': 'Total' });
        $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { background: 'red'});


    }
```

What am I doing wrong? How would I make this !important if that is the cause?

Comment: Do you want to set the background color on the whole footer row or on some specific cell? Do you want to set the color based on the value `colSum` (you set it inside of `gridComplete` callback ever time) or just to set some color independent on the sum value? You place the text in the columns `totals` and `day7`. Do you use formatters in the columns?

Comment: This might be crazy but does 'background' need to be in single quotes?

Comment: No the quota are not important. The method `footerData` can't be used to set CSS class on the cell or the row. If you want that I help you, please answer on the questions which I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: I want the entire row to be a different color to distinguish it from the rest of the grid rows. It is not dependent on anything, just a static color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS rule for example

```css
.ui-jqgrid-sdiv .ui-jqgrid-ftable .footrow {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none
}
```

The method `footerData` don't support any parameter which allow you to change the color dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Works great.